# OpenGLRenderer flushing caches (mode 0) and (mode 1)

Tags: android, openglrenderer

Whenever I install my application, I am able to copy database from asset folder to `/data/data/packagename/databases/` . Till this, application works very fine.

But after 10 or 15 seconds, all cache folders like `cache/SharedPreference/databases`, all folders which are available in `/data/data/packagename/databases/` got deleted and in logcat I got this error.

```
03-25 12:40:38.771: D/OpenGLRenderer(12660): Flushing caches (mode 0)
03-25 12:40:38.810: D/OpenGLRenderer(12660): Flushing caches (mode 1)
```

After searching on Google for cause of this error, I found that if APK size exceeds 50MB, flushing caches error occurs. But in my case APK size is 35MB only.

Comment: an unknown trouble? :)

Comment: @Downvoter explain cause for downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but i had a same issue. The problem is the program uses too much memory location (RAM problem). Solution is reducing uses of RAM or using garbage collection like `System.gc()`. If memory capacity of the device is very low, any solution is not exist.